# Django - Need helping writing annotated query

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to better understand how to write some more advanced queries. I'm used to the basic Model.objects.all() and .filter(), etc, but I'm having trouble writing out queries that are annotated.

Here is my model setup (I have removed any additional fields that are not necessary for this question):

```
from django.db import models

class Client(models.Model): 
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Project(models.Model): 
    client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Campaign(models.Model): 
    project = models.ForeignKey(Project, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="campaigns")

class Advertisement(models.Model): 
    campaign = models.ForeignKey(Campaign, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='advertisements')
```

What I need is a query that shows how many Advertisements each client has, ordered by most to least.

I'm trying to follow the docs from here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/aggregation/ but their annotation example isn't as nested, the publisher model example is a foreign key on the book object, where as with mine the client is a foreign key of a project, which is a foreign key of a campaign, which is a foreign key of advertisements.

Any advice on how to drill down through the layers of the models to get the info I need?

Answer (score 0):

On Django ORM, the joins that navigate the relationships are done with `__`.
You can keep on nesting the relationship traversal.
This would make your query something like the following.

```py
Client.objects.annotate(num_advertisements=Count('project__campaigns__advertisements'))
```

The names `campaigns` and `advertisements` have to be used because of the `related_name` you set.